# Bluetooth Not Working on Debian: "No default controller available"

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I'm facing an issue with Bluetooth on my Debian system, and I'm seeking assistance to troubleshoot and resolve the problem.

Here are the details:

**Issue:**
When I try to scan for Bluetooth devices using `bluetoothctl`, I encounter the following error: `No default controller available`.

**System Information:**

- OS: Debian
- Bluetooth Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros AR3011
- Bluetooth Service: Active and running
- Bluetoothctl Command: `scan on`

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

1. Checked Bluetooth service status: `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service` \

```bash
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabl>
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-11-20 10:20:39 CET; 4h 42min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1780 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 80ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1780 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=audio,a2dp
```

2. Checked for loaded bluetooth kernel modules:\

```bash
lsmod | grep btusb
btusb 53248 0
```

```bash
lsmod | grep ath3k
ath3k 20480 0
```

3. Checked for firmware package: `firmware-atheros is installed`.
4. Checked Bluetooth-related messages in dmesg:

```bash
sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   20.367747] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   20.367793] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   20.367796] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   20.367810] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   20.367814] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   20.367824] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.844567] Bluetooth: Can't change to loading configuration err
[  172.268002] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  172.268012] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  172.268020] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm unable to use Bluetooth functionality on my Debian system.

Comment: I had the same problem on fedora 39, you can follow this website. It worked for me after I couldn't find any other solutions.
I used blueman, after enabling bluetooth and starting bluetooth it works via blueman and the gnome settings
Website: https://www.howtogeek.com/829360/how-to-set-up-bluetooth-on-linux/